# How to close third party excel addin dialog with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the image of the popup exception

[image]

Hi, I have a sub which refreshes every 1 min a third party (Canary) addin calculation. The problem is that sometimes it poups up this exception which I can't supress it with application.displayalerts=False.

Comment: You should use Spy++ or something similar to see al the hierarcy of the dialog children windows. Then, using APIs (FindWindow, FindWindowEx and SendMessage) you can identify the control you want pressing and do that programmatically (using SendMessage).

Comment: The problem would be that you cannot do it from the same Excel session. You have to use another session, or another application using VBA (Word, CorelDRAW etc.). You should create there a timer waiting for window having the title „Canary Labs - Diagnostic Display”.

Comment: Perhaps you can fix whatever is causing the add-in to enter an error condition. If it is a genuine error, perhaps trying to programmatically suppress it isn't the best approach. You could also try to contact the makers of the add-in. In desperation, you could experiment with `Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}", True`, though perhaps the pop-up will prevent your code from getting to that line while the pop-up is displayed.